# How does Branch construct the url that's ultimately hidden in the *.app.link url?

Tags: branch.io

I'm creating a branch link - which I can only test with the live version of the app - as such:

```
    let routeString = "create"
    let buo = BranchUniversalObject(canonicalIdentifier: PFUser.current()!.objectId!)
    let linkProperties = BranchLinkProperties()
    linkProperties.feature = "createItem"
    linkProperties.addControlParam("$deeplink_path", withValue: routeString)
    linkProperties.addControlParam("referrer", withValue: "someApp")
```

I assume this creates a link such as `https://myApp.app.link/create?referrer=someApp`

Is that correct or are the linkProperties constructed into some other shape? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Jackie from Branch here. Creating Branch links via SDK as you have, will generate short links that look like this: https:myApp.app.link/fbofj2(random characters). The link includes all the data and parameters you set during the creation.

Long links, on the other hand, have link properties appended to the link URL itself. This can be dynamically created on your end like so: https:myApp.app.link/?foo=bar.

To learn more, feel free to reference our documentation on link generation: https://docs.branch.io/pages/links/integrate/#short-links